# Why MVC 5 not accepting date with this digits

Tags: date, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following code in MVC model:

```
 public DateTime? RequestDate { get; set; }
```

In the MVC (view), when I enter the date in this format '۱۳۹۶/۰۲/۲۱', the MVC validation is rejecting it and even it is rejected when I enter '۲۰۱۷/۰۵/۱۱' date which is equal to '2017/05/11'.

Any suggestion to work around make it accept the date with the mentioned format?

Comment: You need to update the number to use ASCII characters. So you can't use persian numbers. Also you can't use '۱۳۹۶/۰۲/۲۱' directly, you need .Net localization and use JalaliCalendar object to convert it to Gregorian date

Comment: I am using .Net localization but the problem is that MVC does not allow the characters to be validated. I wanted to get these numbers from MVC View and then convert to equivalent numbers.